# How to wire up table column of NSDictionary key kept in NSUserDefaults array

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nsdictionary, nstableview

So I have a view based tableView, that exposes a dictionary's key and value each as a column, bound to a NSDictionaryController (WeatherLocation), whose content object is from an application item, with bindings as:

[image: Key column]

[image: Value column]

and all is fine but the keys for this dictionary are finite (7 values): cc, city, st, loc, lat, lon, zip, so I want to

1. force user to pick from a list - kept in user default preference array
2. use the dictionary key validation (uniqueness) so values aren't duplicated

But I'm stuck how to wire up the pop-up button cell to the column value; so far for the popup button cell for the key column I have:

[image]

so a view of the tableView shows the key column being the entire array from the defaults pref, not just a single value:

[image]

Comment: A **view** based tableView with a pop-up button **cell** doesn't sound right.

Comment: Actually I have tried both table types (view,cell). Ideally I'd like to source the pop-up menu from user defaults - language locale, vs in IB but either is fine. It's how to wire the column or cell value is where I'm stuck. Getting past this I'll handle exceptions if a duplicate entry is attempted using a tableView delegate.

Comment: I woud recommend using a view based table view. Is `weatherLocationKeys` in the user preferences what you expect, an array of strings?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqkh0hd9m0agjaq/popup.zip?dl=0 

contains a model of what I'm attempting.  The user preference is an array of the dictionary keys, but the dictionary itself is part of an application object; in this sample - popup, I placed the dictionary into the user preferences as well.  It doesn't matter if the key list comes from the array in the prefs or the popup menu cell for me, I just need a finite key set and use the dictionary object to maintain uniqueness.

Comment: Remove all bindings of the popupbuttoncell. Select the Key column, bind Content Values to `weatherLocationKeys` of userdefaults and bind Selected Value to `key` of the dictionarycontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is posted on [github](https://github.com/slashlos/popup); thanks to all for guiding me.

The column bindings, and only those needed are

[image]

This sample shows using defaults to store all information, a dictionary via popup for key value entry, and a delegate stub to validate value of key/value pair.  Enjoy.

Comment: Note: this is a cell based table view. When I try this in a view based table view, Xcode (ibtool) gets stuck in a loop and eats all my memory.

Comment: A dictionary keeps these key/value pairs in an item dictionary; they keys are kept separate in a user preference array loaded by the app.

Using the github sample I posted, I altered tableview to be cell based, then dragged the popupbutton cell up, to just under the 'Key' column - still works. 

Attempt to pick a key already used to yields a built-in sheet alert -
 popover to provide a valid value.